# Where to put trim_blocks setting for the Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I wonder where to put `trim_blocks` setting for the template module in Ansible? What is the configuration file I will need to edit?

Comment: Typo, meant `trim_blocks`.

Answer (score 2):

[trim_blocks](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/?highlight=trim#whitespace-control) can be put into the header of the Jinja template. For example

```
$ cat templates/my_template.j2
#jinja2: trim_blocks:False
{%- for host in groups.test %}
{{ host }}
{%- endfor %}
```